# strncat & strncpy help c++

Tags: c++, buffer, cstring

So my assignment is:

> Using the `strncpy` and `strncat` functions in `#include<cstring>`,
>   implement a function
>
> ```
> void concat(const char a[ ], const char b[ ], char result[ ],
>                  int result_maxlength)
> ```
>
> that concatenates the strings `a` and `b` to the buffer `result`.  Be sure
>   not to overrun the result. It can hold `result_maxlength` characters,
>   not counting the `\0` terminator.  (That is, the buffer has
>   `buffer_maxlength + 1` bytes available.)  Be sure to provide a ‘\0’
>   terminator.

My solution (thus far) is below but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Not only do I get a run-time check failure 2 error when I actually run the program, but I'm unsure where I should be adding the `\0` terminator or even if I should be using `strncat` rather than `strncpy`. Hopefully someone can lead me in the right direction. And  yes this is hw. That's why I said just lead me in the right direction so that I can try to figure it out :p

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

void concat(const char a[ ], const char b[ ], char result[ ], int result_maxlength);

int main()
{
    char a[] = "Woozle";
    char b[] = "Heffalump";
    char c[5];
    char d[10];
    char e[20];

    concat(a, b, c, 5);
    concat(a, b, d, 10);
    concat(a, b, e, 20);
    cout << c << "\n";
    cout << d << "\n";
    cout << e << "\n";

    return 0;
}

void concat(const char a[ ], const char b[ ], char result[ ], int result_maxlength)
{    
    strncat(result, a, result_maxlength);
    strncat(result, b, result_maxlength);
}
```

Comment: What *is* `strsply`? I've never heard of it, and Google doesn't seem to have either.

Comment: You probably want the first of the two `strncat`s to be a `strncpy`.

Comment: Yes, `strncat` will look for a 0 to know where to start appending, and who knows where that could be.

Comment: If this is homework, please indicate that that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. strncpy from a to result (whatever is smaller, lenght of a or result_maxlength)
2. strncat from b to **remaining** of result  (whatever is smaller, lenght of b or result_maxlength- lenght of a)
3. before every return just put a \0 at last position `result[result_maxlength-1] ='\0';`

It's actually not specified WHAT to do if result is too short, should you add trailing 0 or not. I guess you'd better terminate that string.

tip : remaining of result is `result+strlen(a)`

Comment: I'm trying to use this code and it's doing everything I want it to except an overrun error keeps popping up.           strncpy (result,a, result_maxlength);
 strncat (result, b, result_maxlength);
 result[result_maxlength-1] = '\0';

Comment: @BreezeonholdOn: the problem is in your call to `strncat()` - you can't simply pass in `result_maxlength` because there's not that much room left in the buffer (some or all of the buffer is used by the copy of `a`).  You need to read Agent_L's answer carefully, particularly the bits about "whatever is smaller".

Answer (score 2):

At the very least your `result` is uninitialized before the first `strncat` in `concat`.

*EDIT*: And yes, as Michael Burr points out your result size is supposed to be changing as you progress and calculated from the very start. Actually, it is misleading name you picked, because it is the max size of source, not destination.

Answer (score 2):

The last argument to `strncat()` represents the *remaining* space available in the buffer - not the full size of the buffer.

Also note that that argument includes the spot that the terminating null character will need, so you'll need to account for that since the spec for `concat()` is otherwise.

Finally, according to the `concat()` spec, the result placed in the buffer should not be concatenated to the existing contents of the buffer (those contents should be replaced).  Also, make sure you test that your function properly handles a zero length `result_maxlength` argument being passed in.